# Change shipping cost depending on ACF field and exclude certain shipping methods

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, hook-woocommerce, shipping-method

I'm trying to add an extra shipping cost for all the additional shipping fees that aren't calculated from the third party shipping
company:

```php
//add additional extra cost to shipping except for local pickup
    
        add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'shipping_extra_cost' );
        function shipping_extra_cost( $rates ) {
        
            
            foreach($rates as $key => $rate ) {
                $rates[$key]->cost = $rates[$key]->cost + get_field('extra_cost', "51");
            }
    
        return $rates;
    }
```

But then the additional fee is also added on local shipping
which is wrong.

I can't work with WC shipping classes because that messes with the third party shipping calculation program.

Is there a way I can check if "local pickup" exists and then exclude the extra fee from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exclude 1 or more shipping methods by using `$rate->method_id`

**Note:** because `get_field()` only applies when using the ACF plugin I replaced it with a fixed number, adjust to your needs

So you get:

```php
function filter_woocommerce_package_rates( $rates, $package ) {
    //$field = get_field( 'extra_cost', '51' );

    $field = 50;

    // Multiple can be added, separated by a comma
    $exclude = array( 'local_pickup' );

    // Loop through
    foreach ( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ) {
        // Targeting
        if ( ! in_array( $rate->method_id, $exclude ) ) {
            // Set the new cost
            $rates[$rate_key]->cost += $field;
        }
    }

    return $rates;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates','filter_woocommerce_package_rates', 10, 2 );
```

---

For **debugging purposes** you can temporarily use:

```php
function filter_woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label( $label, $method ) {
    // Getters
    $id = $method->id;
    $method_id = $method->method_id;

    // Output
    $label .= '<span style="color:red; font-size:20px; display:block;">Id = ' . $id . '</span>';
    $label .= '<span style="color:red; font-size:20px; display:block;">Method id = ' . $method_id . '</span>';

    return $label; 
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label', 'filter_woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label', 10, 2 );
```

Result:

[image]