# Change payment method title based on selected shipping method in WooCommerce checkout

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, shipping-method, payment-method

I`m trying to make a switch on (COD) cash on delivery label if the delivery option is selected

The user has 2 options on delivery:

```html
<input type="radio" name="shipping_method[0]" data-index="0" id="shipping_method_0_samedaycourier724" value="samedaycourier:7:24" class="shipping_method">
<input type="radio" name="shipping_method[0]" data-index="0" id="shipping_method_0_samedaycourier15ln" value="samedaycourier:15:LN" class="shipping_method" checked="checked">
```

If the *value="samedaycourier:15:LN"* is checked I want the COD label to be  Credit Card on Delivery instead of Cash on Delivery

I copied a similar code and tried to adapt it to my need, unfortunately without the desired result. Any advice?

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_payment', 'customizing_payment_option', 10, 0 );
function customizing_payment_option(){

$text1  = __( 'Cash on Delivery', 'woocommerce' );
$text2  = __( 'Credit Card on EasyBox', 'woocommerce' );

?>
<script>
    jQuery(function($){

        // 1. Initialising once loaded
        if($('input[name^="shipping_method[0]"]:checked').val() == 'samedaycourier:15:LN' )
            $('input[id^="payment_method_cod"]').text('<?php echo $text2; ?>');
        else
            $('input[id^="payment_method_cod"]').text('<?php echo $text1; ?>');

        // 2. Live event detection:When shipping method is changed
        $( 'form.checkout' ).on( 'change', 'input[name^="shipping_method[0]"]', function() {
            var choosenDeliveryMethod = $('input[name^="shipping_method[0]"]:checked').val(); // Chosen

            if( choosenDeliveryMethod == 'samedaycourier:15:LN' )
                $('input[id^="payment_method_cod"]').text('<?php echo $text2; ?>');
            else 
                $('input[id^="payment_method_cod"]').text('<?php echo $text1; ?>');
        });
    });
</script>
<?php
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use jQuery, you can use the `woocommerce_gateway_title` filter hook and `WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' )`

Adjust `$payment_id === ''` and the result of `$chosen_shipping_methods` to your needs

So you get:

```php
function filter_woocommerce_gateway_title( $title, $payment_id ) {
    // Only on checkout page and for COD
    if ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() && $payment_id === 'cod' ) {
        // Get chosen shipping methods
        $chosen_shipping_methods = (array) WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );

        // Compare
        if ( in_array( 'local_pickup:1', $chosen_shipping_methods ) ) {
            $title = __( 'My title', 'woocommerce' );
        } elseif ( in_array( 'lsamedaycourier:7:24', $chosen_shipping_methods ) ) {
            $title = __( 'Credit Card on Delivery', 'woocommerce' );
        } else {
            $title = __( 'Another title', 'woocommerce' );
        }
    }

    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_gateway_title', 'filter_woocommerce_gateway_title', 10, 2 );
```

---

**Note:** to find the correct `$chosen_shipping_methods` (ID), you can use (part 2) "For debugging purposes" from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72089957/11987538)

Answer (score 0):

This is what i used for EasyBox services (is a modified code from bbloomer):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'bbloomer_gateway_disable_for_shipping_rate' );
  
function bbloomer_gateway_disable_for_shipping_rate( $available_gateways ) {
   if ( ! is_admin() ) {
      $chosen_methods = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );
      $method_key_id = $chosen_methods[0];
      if ( isset( $available_gateways['cod'] ) && 0 === strpos( $method_key_id, 'samedaycourier:15:LN' ) ) {
         unset( $available_gateways['cod'] );
      }
   }
   return $available_gateways;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).