# Shipping discount in WooCommerce based on cart subtotal

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, discount

I want to activate a shipping cost discount based on the cart subtotal.

Examples:

- Order subtotal above R$ 350 -> get 50% of Shipping Discount
- Order subtotal above R$ 450 -> get 70% of Shipping Discount

Therefore, I use the following code:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'fa_woocommerce_package_rates', 10, 2 );
function fa_woocommerce_package_rates( $rates, $package ) {

    foreach ( $rates as $key => $rate ) {
        $cost = $rate->get_cost();

        // todos os métodos
        $rate->set_cost( $cost * 0.5 ); // 0.5 = 50%

        $rates[ $key ] = $rate;
    }

    return $rates;
}
```

It works, but i'm struggling to make these rules. Any help would be apreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To determine the shipping discount based on the subtotal you can use the 2nd argument passed to the filter hook, namely: `$package`. Then you use: `$package['cart_subtotal']`

So you get:

```php
function filter_woocommerce_package_rates( $rates, $package ) {
    // Get subtotal
    $subtotal = $package['cart_subtotal'];
    
    // Greater than
    if ( $subtotal > 350 ) {
        // 50% discount
        $percentage = 50;

        // If more, adjust percentage
        if ( $subtotal > 450 ) {
            // 70% discount
            $percentage = 70;
        }

        // Loop trough
        foreach ( $rates as $rate_id => $rate ) {
            // Get rate cost
            $cost = $rate->get_cost();

            // New rate cost
            $rate->set_cost( $cost - ( $cost * $percentage ) / 100 );
        }
    }   
    
    return $rates;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'filter_woocommerce_package_rates', 10, 2 );
```

---

To target certain shipping methods, change:

```php
// Loop trough
foreach ( $rates as $rate_id => $rate ) {
    // Get rate cost
    $cost = $rate->get_cost();

    // New rate cost
    $rate->set_cost( $cost - ( $cost * $percentage ) / 100 );
}
```

To:

```php
// Loop trough
foreach ( $rates as $rate_id => $rate ) {
    // Get rate cost
    $cost = $rate->get_cost();

    // Targeting shipping method, several can be added, separated by a comma
    if ( array_intersect( array( $rate->method_id, $rate_id ), array( 'flat_rate', 'flat_rate:3' ) ) ) {
        // New rate cost
        $rate->set_cost( $cost - ( $cost * $percentage ) / 100 );
    }
}
```

---

**Hint:** for debugging purposes you can temporarily use [the second part from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72089957/11987538)